# Plotting a Model created with PyMC3 as a graph

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, pymc3

I am using the following code to create a simple Model with PyMC3:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

with pm.Model() as model:
    p = pm.Uniform("freq_cheating", 0, 1)
    p_skewed = pm.Deterministic("p_skewed", 0.5*p + 0.25)

    yes_responses = pm.Binomial("number_cheaters", 100, p_skewed, observed= 50) 

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(25000, step=step)
    burned_trace50 = trace[2500:]
```

Is it possible to plot this model as a DAG?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Added in version 3.5](https://medium.com/@pymc_devs/say-hello-to-pymc-3-5-a375e1acab9d) is the `model_to_graphviz` method, which does exactly that.  For your example above, you'd use

```
pm.model_to_graphviz(model)
```

[image]